# Create 2 buttons in android platform and link them to 2 buttons in a webpage

Tags: android

I am new to this and hope someone could give me an idea or direction so that I can work on it.

I am working on a project which requires me to create few big buttons in an android phone to control the pan-tilt of an IP camera. This IP camera comes with a webpage which the staff could access but due to the age of the staff, it will be easier to create some buttons in a phone and link it to the few frequent used function for them to press on it rather than going through the webpage.

I hope I am clear with my question and I appreciate any help/advice from this community.

Comment: You can open the same web page in a webview on the phone

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through some online tutorial on webview and work on it.

Comment: In order to access the webpage, I will need to enter the username and password. Currently, I am using an app(DashLane in android) to help me to perform an auto log-in. After the auto-login, I just want to show only the few buttons which are located within the webpage for the staff to access. Staff do not need to zoom-in/out to make the buttons bigger. Is this possible still with webview?

Comment: answer given by Sourav  is correct. Even I tried the same thing but I didn't find anything. You can send HTML button event to android by @JavascriptInterface but I didn't find anything how to send android button event to HTML Button. But you can do one thing is that. load that pages int webview put android button below webview and do the same thing as you are doing by your HTML button. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

On Button click event write this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

that open the your URL.
Also you can use webview to show your web content inside your app without opening a web browser app.

Comment: Hi Sourav, Thanks a lot for your advice and coding you have placed in your comments. Although I dont understand it for the time being, I will spend my next few days to work on this.